# Non Intel Hardware?

Tags: arm

How fully is pcDuino supported ?
I see an advert on Linksprite for pcDuino models using the Allwinner A10 and ARM Cortex A8.

Are these considered Intel compatible?
I'm wondering about compatibility with applications like LibreOffice?

Comment: Allwiner CPUs are not Intel compatible, and, as far as I know, pcDuino is not directly supported by Canonical/Ubuntu. That said, there are Ubuntu 12.04 (more likely Lubuntu) images on Linksprite, presumably provided by pcDuino vendor, and Ubuntu has armf repositories which incude LibreOffice. I don't know how well it works, or what your specific needs are. Search for reviews of the board you have in mind. There are also many more similar ARM based boards that run Lubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Visit the [LinkSprite pcDuino](http://www.linksprite.com/?page_id=782) and you will see a list of images for various models of pcDuino. Click on the *Image for pcDuinoX* link where for the X substitute your pcDuino's model number. Clicking the link will take you to a webpage that has a list of the available Ubuntu images for that model number pcDuino.